# custom rails form validation for email/url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form which takes two radio buttons, E-Mail OR URL. In my model, these two fields are required but I only want **one** of them to be depending on the radio button clicked.

Potential solution: Add hidden field and pass params into model where I can validate?

```
<%= form_for @webhook do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox email">
            <label>
                <%= f.radio_button :show_url_form, 0, checked: true %>
                Lorum Ipsum 
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox url">
            <label>
                <%= f.radio_button :show_email_form, 1, checked: false %>
                Lorum Ipsum 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group url">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.hidden_field :perform_validation, value: true %>
            <%= f.label :url %>
            <%= f.text_field :url, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group email" style="display: none;">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <%= f.radio_button :format, 'formatone' %> formatone
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <%= f.radio_button :format, 'formattwo' %> formattwo
        </label>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

model:

```
validates :url, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you can add a condition to both validtions...

```
attr_accessor :skip_url_validations
attr_accessor :skip_email_validations

validates_presence_of :url, unless: :skip_url_validations
validates_presence_of :email, unless: :skip_email_validations
```

Then in your controller you can set either skip_url or skip_email to true depending on the params passed in by the form...something like this

```
@webhook = Webhook.new(webhook_params)
@webhook.skip_email_validations = true if params.has_key?(:url)
@webhook.skip_url_validations = true if params.has_key?(:email)
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I was thinking. There is no neater way to do this?

Comment: You could create a private method in the controller to wrap the `true if params.has_key?(:key)` logic.

Comment: Well you gave me confidence in my solution. It’s correct to me :)